# Sending scheduled email via Gmail SMTP API

Tags: api, smtp, gmail, schedule

Is there a way to send a scheduled, say, three days latter, email via gmail api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, pretty sure there's no such API call (yet). I'd recommend creating the email as a draft and set up some kind of scheduled task to send it out later.

In case you're using Google App engine, you could use [cron service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron).